# Switching to SpringMVC from PlayFramework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, playframework

I am migrating from PlayFramework 1.* (java) to SpringMVC (but not using SpringBoot). I have some questions about the transition:

1) In Play framework there is an opportunity to show an error in a browser, when you deploy an app in dev mode. As I understood in Spring there is nothing like that, but I always see error pages with 500 http code when errors occur. That is no good for users to see those exception logs. In Play it is easy to stop showing those messages to users by switching to prod mode, but how to do that in Spring? (I deploy the webapp to tomcat7).

2) Is there any way in SpringMVC to get a path to any controller as it can be done in Play's template engine with @{Controller.action} tag? In Spring I use JSP for rendering web pages.

3) In examples of Play projects I saw before, properties like URLs of external resources or some texts are stored in .conf files that are divided into development.conf, production.conf etc. Play loads them (not automatically hough) depending on which server is running the application. Is there a way to create and load such kinds of property files in Spring and make it easier to switch between those configurations on different servers?

Comment: There's all sorts of things possible with Spring. They're all described in the manual(s). This question is too broad to answer as is.

Comment: @Kayaman, could you please help me to find those technologies or manuals? I tried, I swear

Comment: If you can't even do basic Google searches, how do you expect to learn to program. Give me a break.

Comment: This is too broad and you should ask these questions as separated discussions. Also, try to follow the stackoverflow guideline about how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to web programming and Spring MVC and Play I wouldn't start learning with the combination of Play and Spring. I recommend start either with Spring or with Play. Nearly everything you can do with Spring MVC you can do with Play itself too and if it is dependency injection you are after then Play comes with [Guice out of the box](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection).

For Spring I'd recommend starting with Spring Boot (and MVC of course). There is a good [tutorial on their site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

For Play I'd recommend their [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/). You could also look at [Lightbend's templates](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates) and filter for Java, e.g. this one seems to be [a good starting point for a simple web](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-java-reactive-platform-15v09) app.